# What is the easiest way to make a self extracting PE?

Tags: self, extract, portable-executable

One way is to concatenate the PEs as mentioned in this article: 
http://www.strchr.com/creating_self-extracting_executables

Is there a more convenient way to do it?

I don't want to iterate through every PE section just to find the size of the PE.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy methods (API) to do this. As the URL (thanks for sharing it!) shows, one must handle the target image programmatically and discover to positions and sizes, etc...of the sections.